# Getting 400 on Flask Unit Test

Tags: python, unit-testing, flask

I'm writing a unit test for a file upload function in Flask.

The app works well locally but the unit test throws a 400. Thanks!

Here's my app.py

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config["TESTING"] = True


@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/uploader', methods = ['GET','POST'] )
def upload_photo():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        photo = request.files['photo']
        resp = app.make_response(photo.read())  
        resp.mimetype = 'image/jpeg'
        return resp

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Here's my test:

```
import unittest
import io
from app import app


class TestCase(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.client = app.test_client()

    def test_upload_photo(self):            
        result = self.client.post('/uploader', 
    content_type='multipart/form-data', follow_redirects=True, 
    data=dict(upload_var=(io.BytesIO(b'photo'), 'photo')))
        print(result.data) 
        self.assertTrue(result.status_code == 200)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()`
```

Comment: Could you include the traceback of the error?

Comment: @LuisOrduz When I do traceback I get the following output: `NoneType: None`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `upload_var` to `photo` in the data dictionary, as that's what your handler function is expecting the file to be called.

Comment: Thanks @Luis Orduz, that worked well.  I knew it was something like that!